# T-SQL transaction encounters errors but is not canceled

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, transactions

By definition T-SQL transaction should be cancelled if any statement inside it results with error. However, I stumbled upon the situation where transaction passes with an error happening in the middle of it.

Example environment setup:

```
--test tables:
IF OBJECT_ID('t2', 'U') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE t2;  
GO      
IF OBJECT_ID('t1', 'U') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP TABLE t1;  
GO     

CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);  
CREATE TABLE t2  (a INT NOT NULL REFERENCES t1(a));  
GO      

INSERT INTO t1 
VALUES (1), (3), (4), (6);  
GO
```

Transaction test:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
     INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1); 
     INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2); -- Foreign key error will be thrown.  
     INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3);  

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

This should have been cancelled because of the foreign key error, but it isn't:

```
SELECT * FROM t2;
```

results with two rows returned - values 1 and 3.

Adding `SET XACT_ABORT ON` does the job, but how is it possible that entire transaction holds up when there's an error in the middle of it?

Comment: "By defination" of who?!? This is well documented and all behaves as expected. You should simply read the real definition in the BOL: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql`. from the BOL: "`When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues processing.`"

Comment: No such thing as "cancelled if there's an error". Transactions just commit all or nothing. That's it.

Comment: @RonenAriely I am referring to the BOL: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017`, section  `"If a transaction encounters errors and must be canceled or rolled back, then all of the data modifications are erased."` This is the part that raised my question. Thank you for pointing out the part you did, but I wanted to find out what `in some cases` actually means.

Comment: You're ignoring the part after `and`. They're separate conditions. In this case, the transaction doesn't need to be cancelled or rolled back, so that `must` doesn't apply. I think you were reading it as the part before the `and` *implying* the part after.

Comment: "`what in some cases actually means`": this is different question which is actually good one. @Damien_The_Unbeliever gave you a good explanation. You misunderstood the sentence you quoted. The idea is that IF MUST be canceled or rolled back, then all of the data modifications are erased. Adding SET XACT_ABORT ON is exactly one way to make it "a `must be canceled` on error", another option is to use ROLLBACK (for example as Dan show in his example).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the specific error, the T-SQL batch will continue after an error without `XACT_ABORT ON`. I recommend `TRY/CATCH` with `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;` in the `CATCH BLOCK` plus `XACT_ABORT ON` to make sure the rollback occurs immediately in the case of a query cancel or client timeout (which prevents the `CATCH` block from being executed):

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1); 
    INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2); -- Foreign key error will be thrown.  
    INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3);  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
END CATCH;
```